# How do I upload in a batch large files to AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I want to do a backup of a Linux file server which has 1.4 TB of data to AWS S3 Standard - IA. Some of the files are large, over 100 MB, and I read that multipart should be used. How can I do this on the command line so it does a sync, but handles the larger files automatically?

For example, I want to backup all of /home and /root recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [aws-cli tool](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) has two sets of S3 commands: `s3api` to directly invoke specific APIs (e.g. `aws s3api put-object`) and `s3` for user-level abstractions (like `aws s3 cp` or `aws s3 sync`).

The latter set will use S3 multipart upload automatically for files larger than 8Mb, it even has a `multipart_threshold` configuration option to customize the behaviour.